# Exclude view from blurring android

Tags: android, video, blur

I am having a `VideoView` in my application.

I have set blur flags in my activity

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
```

The problem is even the video in the `VideoView` is blurring, which I don't want.

When `VideoView` is replaced by an `ImageView` with a specified source, its not blurry at all.

Is there any solution to avoid this blur in `VideoView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because a VideoView creates a surface behind your application's surface. The FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND flag blurs all the surfaces under your application's surface. This is why the ImageView is not blurry because it is in your application's surface, not in a surface behind it.

Comment: Hello sir :) I respect you and your contribution to Android. Is there any workaround for this ?

Comment: There is a new API on SurfaceView you can use to move the SurfaceView's surface on *top* of your activity's surface.